# How to print a the same map result 5 times in a loop?

Tags: python

Here I've a simple assoc. array of maps where I want to loop, but I want to print the arr['b'] by repeating 5 times.

```
number = 0
arr = {}
arr['a'] = map(float, [1, 2, 3])
arr['b'] = map(float, [4, 5, 6])
arr['c'] = map(float, [7, 8, 9])
arr['d'] = map(float, [10, 11, 12])

while number < 5:
    print(list(arr['b']))
    number = number + 1
```

Why is the output as such, instead of `[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]` repeating 5 times? How can I loop to get `arr['b']` result 5 times?

```
Output:
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

This is the output I really want.

```
Intended Output:
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
[4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 4):

`map` produces a generator which gets consumed the first time you access its content. Therefore, the first time you convert it to a list, it gives you the expected results, but the second time the resulting list is empty. Simple example:

```
a = map(float, [1, 2, 3])
print(list(a))
# out: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
print(list(a))
# out: []
```

Convert the map object/generator to a list once (outside the loop!) and you can print it as often as you need: `arr['a'] = list(map(float, [1, 2, 3]))` etc.

---

Other improvement: In Python you don't need counters in loops as you use it here. Instead, in order to do something 5 times, rather use `range` (the `_` by convention denotes a value we are not interested in):

```
for _ in range(5):
    print(list(arr['b']))
```

Comment: TQ mcsoini... very helpful!!!

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it solves you problem.